# public repository with gitolite

Tags: git, ubuntu-10.04, gitolite

I installed an configured gitolite and it works for some other projects I'm working on. However, I want to set up a public repo that anyone call clone from (but not push).

I've searched everywhere and cannot find a way to do this? Has anyone managed to do this with gitoite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like [this guy](http://blog.tampakrap.gr/gitolite-installation-with-gitweb-and-anongit-in-gentoo-and-debian/) has done it and provides a HowTo for Debian and Gentoo. Using the *git daemon* is the solution.

Comment: Broken link (blank page)

Answer (score 1):

Building on **eckes**' answer, adding *daemon* as a read-only user to any repo will render it accessible via the git:// protocol, assuming you have git-daemon configured (ships with git, may require minimal configuration).

While I haven't verified the exact process for GNU/Linux, on FreeBSD it works like so:

*The following assumes you have a working git + gitolite system configured at /usr/local/git.*

```
# echo 'git_daemon_enable="YES"' >> /etc/rc.conf
# echo 'git_daemon_directory="YES"' >> /etc/rc.conf
# echo 'git_daemon_flags="--syslog --detach --base-path=/usr/local/git"' >> /etc/rc.conf
# service git-daemon start
```

If you want to have *all* repositories automatically public, append **--export-all** to the git_daemon_flags above. Otherwise, add the **daemon** user with at least **R** privileges to whichever repos you want to make public, and gitolite will handle the rest.

**Sources**

- http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/doc/2-admin.html#_specifying_gitweb_and_daemon_access
- http://forums.freebsd.org/showthread.php?t=10810