# make gitolite repository public

Tags: http, ssh, repository, public, gitolite

How we can gain read access to public gitolite repos, without authentiaction?

### More description

As gitolite provide authorization over repos, you can define some repos that all users can access. But about authentication and how this access can be achieved, I couldnt find any appropriate solution.

***gitolite***: *[Gitolite does not do authentication. It only does authorisation.](https://gitolite.com/gitolite/concepts.html#authentication-and-authorisation)*

If we want to use 2 popular git protocol: SSH and HTTP for our works.

I think it is not appropriate to provide public access over ssh for security reason(and not even sure how it can be done). So if we want to have public access over HTTP how can this be achieved?

And it seems that apache had some changes to block unauthenticated access.

***gitolite***: *[This does not seem to happen any more. Apache seems to insist on a userid, period](https://gitolite.com/gitolite/http.html#allowing-unauthenticated-access)*

public repos can define in gitolite conf:

```
repo testing
    RW+     =   @all public
```

where 'public' is defined in [.gitolite.rc](https://gitolite.com/gitolite/http.html#allowing-unauthenticated-access) and @all is for all users.

```
HTTP_ANON_USER      =>  'public',
```

<s>So it seems answers from before 2019 will not work (I tried this work for excluding an uri from authentication but failed):</s>

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16759565/13663683

my config was:

```
    <Location /git>       
        SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/git/public_repo/$" NOPASSWD=true
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Git Access"
        Require valid-user
        AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/git.passwd
        Order Deny,Allow
        Satisfy any
        Deny from all
        Require valid-user
        Allow from env=NOPASSWD
    </Location>
```

And some works where inefficient to implement, because they have overhead:

https://commentedcode.org/blog/2017/06/12/gitolite-public-http-access/

and some works with broken links:

[public repository with gitolite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878230/public-repository-with-gitolite)

TY.

---

### Update

I was able to do this work with some tweak around apache config

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16759565/13663683

This will create public repo with no authentication, but still lack in someway. You need to absolutely define your public repo subtree and this lack dynamic locations.
And more important with this approach you can not define a user to fill this repo, because no-auth route have higher priority.